# Conditional data type conversion | SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a simple case statement that would update the existing **Total** column which has numeric values to:

'A_1' if **Total** is less than 2 or 'B_2' if other values

```
UPDATE BASE_V1
SET TOTAL=
(CASE
WHEN TOTAL<2 THEN 'A_1'
ELSE 'B_2'
END
)

Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'B_2' to data type int
```

I tried using the convert function to change the datatype but doesn't work

```
UPDATE BASE_V1
SET TOTAL=
(CASE
WHEN TOTAL<2 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'A_1')
ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'B_2')
END
)
```

Comment: You can't store `A_1` in a column that is defined as a numeric data type. You can't fix this problem with a manual `CONVERT()`; you need to change the data type of the column (or store that fact in a different column, or don't store it at all and calculate it at query time).

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand. Understood the error.

Comment: Creating a new column: 

    ALTER TABLE BASE_V1 
    ADD TOTAL_BANDS varchar(10)
    GO
    UPDATE BASE_V1
    SET TOTAL_BANDS=
    (CASE
    WHEN TOTAL<2 THEN 'A_1'
    ELSE 'B_2'
    END
    )

Answer (score 0):

If `Total` is a varchar column, then you need to compare it to a string:

```
UPDATE BASE_V1
SET TOTAL=
(CASE
WHEN TOTAL<'2' THEN 'A_1'
ELSE 'B_2'
END
)
```

The `TOTAL<2` forces SQL to try to implicitly convert all values of `Total` to an integer.   Putting the `2` in single quotes makes it a string comparison.